# Component cannot read JSON properties

Tags: react-native

I am trying to figure out why my components are not rendering without errors. I am trying to parse a JSON file that has been saved into a redux store but whenever I call try to reference the redux state through props such as `this.props.response.data.specificJSONObject`. I will instead get an error that states `cannot read property of 'specificJSONObject' of undefined`. This problem has plagued all of my components that need the use of the JSON file in the redux store. I initially found that my redux store was not updating(asked question: [Redux state not being updated after dispatched actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222771/redux-state-not-being-updated-after-dispatched-actions/57227218#57227218)) when making dispatches but have fixed that and now my redux store is able to store the fetched data it needs but I still get the same error as before.

This is my Summary.js screen for Minimal reproducible code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  ImageBackground,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Text,
  FlatList
} from "react-native";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  fetchingSuccess,
  fetchingRequest,
  fetchingFailure,
  fetchData
} from "../data/redux/actions/appActions.js";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import LinkedName from "./LinkedName";
import ArticleBox from "./ArticleBox";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "dimgrey",
    flex: 1
  },
  posLeft: {
    alignItems: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 40,
    left: 25
  },
  posRight: {
    alignItems: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 40,
    left: 175
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#FFF"
  },
  header_text: {
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#FFF"
  },
  image: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 200,
    height: 375,
    width: 375,
    flex: 1
  },
  topPanel: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.9)",
    height: 150,
    width: 300,
    position: "absolute",
    alignSelf: "center",
    flex: 2,
    flexDirection: "column",
    borderRadius: 25,
    borderWidth: 4
  },
  midPanel: {
    backgroundColor: "rgba(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.9)",
    height: 100,
    width: 300,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 120,
    alignSelf: "center",
    flex: 2,
    flexDirection: "column",
    borderRadius: 25,
    borderWidth: 4
  }
});

class Summary extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      taxonA: this.props.response.articles.taxon_a,
      taxonB: this.props.response.articles.taxon_b,
      sciNameA: this.props.response.articles.scientific_name_a,
      sciNameB: this.props.response.articles.scientific_name_b,
      hitRecords: Object.keys(this.props.response.articles.hit_records).map(
        key => ({ key, ...this.props.response.articles.hit_records[key] })
      ),
      TTOL:
        Math.round(this.props.response.articles.sum_simple_mol_time * 10) / 10,
      median: Math.round(this.props.response.articles.sum_median_time * 10) / 10
    };
    // console.log(STORE, this.props.response.articles);
  }
  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log("STATE", this.state);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require("../assets/images/timescale.png")}
          style={styles.image}
          resizeMode="contain"
          alignSelf="center"
        >
          <View style={styles.topPanel}>
            <Text style={styles.header_text}>Query Taxa</Text>
            <View style={styles.posLeft}>
              <Text
                style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "#FFF", fontSize: 17 }}
              >
                Taxon A
              </Text>
              <Text />
              <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.taxonA}</Text>
              <Text />
              <LinkedName
                url={this.state.hitRecords[0].link_taxon_a}
                latinName={this.state.sciNameA}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.posRight}>
              <Text
                style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "#FFF", fontSize: 17 }}
              >
                Taxon B
              </Text>
              <Text />
              <Text style={styles.text}>{this.state.taxonB}</Text>
              <Text />
              <LinkedName
                url={this.state.hitRecords[0].link_taxon_b}
                latinName={this.state.sciNameB}
              />
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.midPanel}>
            <Text style={styles.header_text}>Result</Text>
            <Text />
            <Text style={styles.text}>TTOL: {this.state.TTOL} MYA</Text>
            <Text />
            <Text style={styles.text}>median: {this.state.median} MYA</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: -35, marginLeft: -5 }}>
            <FlatList
              horizontal
              data={this.state.hitRecords}
              renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                  <ArticleBox
                    title={item.title}
                    year={item.year}
                    time={item.time}
                    author={item.author}
                  />
                );
              }}
              itemSeparatorComponent={() => (
                <View
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: "#ff8c00",
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100
                  }}
                />
              )}
            />
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

Summary.propTypes = {
  fetchData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  response: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { response: state };
};

const mapStateToDispatch = dispatch => ({
  fetchData: url => dispatch(fetchData(url))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapStateToDispatch
)(Summary);
```

This is the function where I reference the Redux state through props

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      taxonA: this.props.response.articles.taxon_a,
      taxonB: this.props.response.articles.taxon_b,
      sciNameA: this.props.response.articles.scientific_name_a,
      sciNameB: this.props.response.articles.scientific_name_b,
      hitRecords: Object.keys(this.props.response.articles.hit_records).map(
        key => ({ key, ...this.props.response.articles.hit_records[key] })
      ),
      TTOL:
        Math.round(this.props.response.articles.sum_simple_mol_time * 10) / 10,
      median: Math.round(this.props.response.articles.sum_median_time * 10) / 10
    };
    // console.log(STORE, this.props.response.articles);
  }
```

In this Instance, I built it right when the state was built but in other components, I will set the state through the `componentWillMount` function and the problem will still persist.

My expected output should be no errors and my components render properly. The received output is the red screen will the error message `cannot read property of 'specificJSONObject' of undefined`.

Comment: specificJSONObject is undefined I would log the whole object to see if perhaps the name is spelled wrong or something

Comment: After logging it to the console, It shows that the `this.props.response.articles` is undefined despite the console showing that the redux state has saved a JSON file where `store.getState` is called.

Comment: I'd say look for typos, if that is not I might look more into it at a later date

Answer (score 0):

The Answer in the question linked up top helps to solve this problem, but will explained here as well.

In my Summary Screen, the problem is being mapped to response. If you see the `MapStatetoProps` functions is written like this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { response: state };
};
```

but should be written like this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return { response: state.fetchingStatus };
};
```

due to how my Redux store is set up and dispatches(can be seen in the question linked above)